# Tell Nancy to serialize enums into strings

Tags: c#, nancy

Nancy by default serialize enums into integers when generating JSON response. I need to serialize enums into strings.

There is a way to customize Nancy's JSON serialization by creating [JavaScriptPrimitiveConverter](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Extending-Serialization-with-Converters). For example this is what I did to customize serialization for ONE enum:

Create the customization class:

```
public class JsonConvertEnum : JavaScriptPrimitiveConverter
{
    public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes
    {
        get
        {
            yield return typeof(MyFirstEnum);
        }
    }

    public override object Deserialize(
        object primitiveValue, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (type == typeof(MyFirstEnum))
        {
            var serialized = (string)primitiveValue;
            MyFirstEnum deserialized;
            if (Enum.TryParse(serialized, out deserialized))
            {
                return deserialized;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public override object Serialize(
        object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (obj is MyFirstEnum)
        {
            var deserialized = (MyFirstEnum)obj;
            var serialized = deserialized.ToString();
            return serialized;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Register it during bootstrap:

```
protected override void ApplicationStartup(
    Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer container, Nancy.Bootstrapper.IPipelines pipelines)
{
    base.ApplicationStartup(container, pipelines);
    Nancy.Json.JsonSettings.PrimitiveConverters.Add(new JsonConvertEnum());
}
```

I need to do this for ALL of my enums.

Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't had the time to test it myself, but the following code should work for all `Enum` types

```
public class JsonConvertEnum : JavaScriptPrimitiveConverter
{
    public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes
    {
        get
        {
            yield return typeof(Enum);
        }
    }

    public override object Deserialize(
        object primitiveValue, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (!type.IsEnum)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return Enum.Parse(type, (string)primitiveValue);
    }

    public override object Serialize(
        object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (!obj.GetType().IsEnum)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return obj.ToString();
    }
}
```

Basically it uses the `Type` metadata to determine if it is an `Enum` or not and then makes use of `Enum.Parse(...)` to convert it from the primitive value back to the correct enum. To convert from `Enum` to `string` all you have to do is to cast the value to a `string`

It can be made more terse by using the ternary operator, but I left the more verbose version for clarity

Hope this helps

Comment: Looks very promising, I'll try it as soon as I can :) Super duper happy path indeed!

Comment: It worked! I used ternary so it becomes one line: `return obj.GetType().IsEnum ? obj.ToString() : null;`.

Comment: Glad I could help =)