# Control deserialization in Nancy 2.0.0

Tags: c#, nancy, json-deserialization

How do I instruct [Nancy](http://nancyfx.org/) **2.0.0**-clinteastwood to do custom deserialization to `DateTime` such as from this json

```
{
    "someDate": "2018-09-18"
}
```

into a `DateTime` property such as in an instance of this C# class

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public DateTime SomeDate { get; set; }
}
```

?

In pre-2.0.0 versions you could [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35193759/1298001) assign your custom `JavaScriptPrimitiveConverter` by a call to the static `JsonSettings` for instance in `ApplicationStartup` like this

```
Nancy.Json.JsonSettings.PrimitiveConverters.Add(new CustomJavaScriptPrimitiveConverter())
```

and I could have implemented the `JavaScriptPrimitiveConverter` Deserialize override for instance like this

```
public override object Deserialize(object primitiveValue, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
{
    if (type == typeof(DateTime))
    {
        if (primitiveValue is string dateString
            && DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal, out var dateTime))
        {
            return dateTime;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

However the static JsonSettings class doesn't seem to be available in 2.0.0.

From searching it appears to me that there is some SimpleJson functionality that might be used to accomplish this, but I can't find any examples, and any documentation I find seems not to be updated with the 2.0.0 way to do things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just as in previous 1.x versions you can use a custom `JsonSerializer` to instruct Nancy about general serialization/deserialization adjustments:

```
public sealed class CustomJsonSerializer : JsonSerializer
{
    public CustomJsonSerializer()
    {
        DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-dd";
        // ... other formatting stuff ...
    }
}
```

And register this `JsonSerializer` with you container, for instance in the `NancyBootStrapper`'s `ConfigureApplicationContainer` like this:

```
protected override void ConfigureApplicationContainer(TinyIoCContainer container)
{
    base.ConfigureApplicationContainer(container);
    container.Register<JsonSerializer, CustomJsonSerializer>();
    // ... other container setup ...
}
```

My problem was that I had missed including the `Nancy.Serialization.JsonNet` NuGet package, which is needed for this to work, for this specific project.

Answer (score 0):

The question is about registering a `PrimitiveConverter` but the answer looks to be registering a `JsonSerializer`.

I was able to register a `PrimitiveConverter` by doing this in `Global.Application_Start` with Nancy 2.0.0:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Nancy.Json.JsonConfiguration.Default.PrimitiveConverters.Add(new CustomJavaScriptPrimitiveConverter());
}
```